# questions and solutions on a csv file

Tags: python, csv, input

How can a system identify the device and load a file specifically for the device which contains suitable questions and responses  such as how many inches is the screen.
I was able to do this on python however I don’t know how to do the same on a csv file.
I have   3 devices that the system should identify however because the code is long I will just show one device .

The user must be able to interact with the program via input.

Comment: can someone help me???

Comment: Do you really need to store your information in a csv-file (basically a table) or can you choose how the data is stored? If you have the freedom to choose, I would highly recommend JSON, because it works better with a hierarchical structure. With JSON you could store your data in a dictionary (e.g.
 `{device1:[(keywords, solution), (keywords, solution)], device2:[(keywords, solution)]}`) and then access it depending on the user input.

Comment: Thanks. i did research on JSON and tried to implement it in my code however it isn't working. can you help me produce the code. a sample would be fine to give me an idea @BurningKarl

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the JSON format to store your data, this gives you more flexibility on how to store data. If your JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "phone": {
        "iphone": {
            "iphone6": {
                "8GB": [
                    [
                        [
                            "keyword1",
                            "keyword2"
                        ],
                        "solution1"
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            "keyword3",
                            "keyword4"
                        ],
                        "solution2"
                    ]
                ],
                "16GB": [
                    ... 
                ]
            },
            "iphone7": {
                "8GB": ...,
                "16GB": ...
            },
        }
        "samsung": ...
    },
    "tablet": ...
}
```

(The `...` represents the data you put there)  Then you can use the user input data directly as keys for your data:

```
import json

# read your data from a file
with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# ask for device
while True:
    device = input("Enter your device: ")
    try:
        device_data = data[device.strip().lower()]
    except KeyError:
        print("Please enter a valid device.")
    else:
        break

# ask for manufacturer
while True:
    manufacturer = input("Enter the manifacturer of your device: ")
    try:
        manufacturer_data = device_data[manufacturer.strip().lower()]
    except KeyError:
        print("Please enter a valid manufacturer.")
    else:
        break

# ask for model
while True:
    model = input("Enter your model: ")
    try:
        model_data = manufacturer_data[model.strip().lower()]
    except KeyError:
        print("Please enter a valid model.")
    else:
        break

# ask for memory
while True:
    memory = input("Enter the amount of internal memory you have: ")
    try:
        memory_data = model_data[memory.strip().lower()]
    except KeyError:
        print("Please enter a valid amount.")
    else:
        break

# ask for problem
while True:
    problem = input("Enter your problem: ")
    words = problem.strip().lower().split(" ")
    for keywords, solution in memory_data:
        if set(words) & set(keywords):
            print(solution)
            break
    else:
        print("A solution could not be found, please describe your problem more clearly.")
```

I included `.strip().lower()` to make more of the possible inputs valid. This accepts `"iphone"`, `"IPhone"`, `"IPHONE"` and `"   Iphone"` as valid inputs. To give your users an overview of what options are possible you could also output the options in your questions. This is an example for manufacturers:

```
options = list(device_data.values())
output = "Enter the manifacturer of your device ["+"/".join(options)+"]: "
manufacturer = input(output)
```

---

This solutions only works if you want to ask the same questions for every device. If this is not the case (e.g. you do not want to ask the user how much internal memory he has when talking about a camera), then you can include the question in the JSON file and ask the questions recursively.

Comment: Can i use the JSON fomat on a notepad

Comment: if you can convert the JSON format into notepad it will be appeciated

Comment: JSON is just a special way to format your data. It consists of normal text and can be written and read by any editor, including Notepad++ or Microsofts Notepad. (There is no need to use `.json` at the end of your data file, you can also call it `data.txt`)